# Stripe Connect create accounts from server

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a stripe connect account using my firebase functions backend when the user signs up but keep getting this error `Express accounts may only be created via the OAuth flow` I know the error seems self-explanatory that I need to use the standard OAuth registration method but in the [Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create) it states that custom types can be created by the API and presenting the OAuth for every user who just wants to send funds and not receive is just annoying am I doing something wrong for the API not to create it? Or is there a workaround to not have to show the OAuth for users who just want to send funds?

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
const account = await stripe.accounts.create({type: 'custom', business_type: 'individual', individual: {email: user.email}, requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers'], email: user.email});
return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({account_id: account.id, customer_id: customer.id});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be being caused by me not specifying the Country in the `stripe.accounts.create` function. Once I did it created the account.

Answer (score 0):

Express Accounts and Custom Accounts are [distinct types of accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) when using Connect. You can create Custom Accounts [using the API](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts), but Express Accounts must be [created via OAuth](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts).

The main difference is that Express Accounts have access to the Stripe Dashboard and can be updated in some ways by the end user, while Custom Accounts are entirely managed by the platform.

Comment: I thought I was creating a custom account while specifying the type

Comment: You're correctly requesting a Custom account when you specify `{ type: "custom" }`. Sounds like you might not be making the request in the way you're expecting, though. I'd suggest contacting [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) or checking out #stripe on Freenode (IRC) since they can look at the actual request logs to see what's being sent in the real calls.